# Angularjs - Test unit directive only numbers

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I have a directives.js file with two directives and I would like apply unit testing necesary, to improve coverage, but I do not know how to do it

This the directive.js file:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('numbersOnly', function(){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                    var transformedInput = inputValue ? inputValue.replace(/[^\d.-]/g,'') : null;
                    if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
                        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        modelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                });
            }
        }
    })
    .directive('numbersOnlyPositive', function(){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                    var transformedInput = inputValue ? inputValue.replace(/[^\d.]/g,'') : null;
                    if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
                        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        modelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                });
            }
        }
    });
 })();
```

This is the tests file (directives.spec.js):

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

    describe('Unit testing directives general', function() {
        var $compile,
            $rootScope,
            element,
            vm;

        // Load the app module, which contains the directive
        beforeEach(module('app'));

        // Store references to $rootScope and $compile
        // so they are available to all tests in this describe block
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
            // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            vm.mesHastaSelected = "3";
            vm.cantidadHastaSelected = "5";
            //element = angular.element('<input text ng-model="mesHastaSelected">');
        }));


        it('should accept number input only', function() {
            expect(vm.cantidadHastaSelected).toBe('1');
        });

        it('should accept number positive input only', function() {
            expect(vm.mesHastaSelected).toBe('8');
        });          

    });
})();
```

This is the html code input fields:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.mesHastaSelected" maxlength="2" numbers-only-positive />
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.cantidadHastaSelected" maxlength="4" numbers-only />
```

Thanks for the help,

Comment: So `1-..-1` is a number? Interesting.

Comment: The directive "numbersOnly" it accepts negative numbers

Comment: Sure, but `1-..-1` is not a number at all.

Comment: [input[number]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) allows you to set the minimum and maximum value for validation already.